# syntax error, unexpected token "{" with Route

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

I'm getting the following error, but I can't figure out where the problem is.

> Syntax error, unexpected token "{"

Can anyone kindly help me?

```
<td onclick="window.location='{{route('beer.show' , compact('beer'))}}'" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <a href="{{route('beer.show' , compact('beer'))}}">{{ $beer->name }}</a>
</td>
```

Comment: try = 

<td onclick="window.location={{route('beer.show' , compact('beer'))}}" style="cursor: pointer;"><a href="{{route('beer.show' , compact('beer'))}}">{{ $beer->name }}</a></td>

Comment: @mrobbizulfikar Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

Comment: is this a `.blade.php` file? as you are getting a javascript error

Answer (score 0):

```
<td onclick="window.location='{{route('beer.show' ,['id'=>$beer->id] )}}'" style="cursor: pointer;">

<a href="{{route('beer.show' ,['id'=>$beer->id]}}">{{ $beer->name }}</a></td>
```

with the help of this id In your controller get your beer

```
$beer = DB::table('table_name')->where('id',$request->id)->first();
```

Comment: so with compact you can not do?